# python kivy : How to make switch Button work with carousel

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I get:

> AttributeError: 'Carousel' object has no attribute 'switch_on'

error whenever I try to click on the button

-------main.py----------

```
class main(App):
    def build(self):



        class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):


            # For Switch
            def switch_on(self, instance, value):
                if value is True:
                    print("Switch On")
                else:
                    print("Switch Off")



        return Carousel()



sample_app = kv_main()
sample_app.run()
```

----------main.kv--------------

:

```
Label:
    text: "Page 1"
    size_hint: 1, .1
    width :100

    SampBoxLayout:


        # ----------Switch ----------
        BoxLayout:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint_x: .25
                CustLabel:
                    text: "On / Off"

                    Switch:
                        id: switch_id
                        on_active: root.switch_on(self, self.active)# <--need help on this


Label:
    text: "Page 2"
    size_hint: 1, .1
    width :100

    Button:
        text: "Button 2.1"
        size_hint: None, None
        width :100



Label:
    text: "Page 3"
    size_hint: 1, .1
    width :100

    Button:
        text: "Button 3.1"
        size_hint: None, None
        width :100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `root.switch_on`. As the error indicates, your root class is the carousel. Since `SampBoxLayout` is not root, you should give `SampBoxLayout` an id, and call it with it´s id.
Edited from your example:

```
SampBoxLayout:
    id: samp
    BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25
            CustLabel:
                text: "On / Off"

                Switch:
                    id: switch_id
                    on_active: samp.switch_on(self, self.active)
```

I don't know if you did something wrong when posting this, or if your code really looks like this. But you should not define classes inside your app class. Keep the classes on top level to access them in kv.
And your kv code is unusual. You have your widgets in a label.

Comment: man! thank you so much! i am new to programming specially gui and I really really really appreciate your help!

Comment: @genesismendoza no problem. Just edited my answer. A little note in the end.

Comment: not really sure what you mean, I only watch youtube videos then try to put them together in one...  can you suggest a better way to do it please? and a book, link, or class recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @genesismendoza well label is usually a widget you put into a layout, like a boxlayout. You seem to do the reverse :)

Comment: ow lol got it, what i mean is the classes inside class App. what should i use? sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @genesismendoza in your app class you define another class. You should not define your class inside the app class, but outside like this http://dpaste.com/0GGP24Q